# change environment size on scale_colour_manual to assign colour to factors to use across multiples plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I need to make 5 plots of bacteria species. Each plot has a different number of species present in a range of 30-90. I want each bacteria to always have the same color in all plots, therefore I need to set an assigned color to each name.
I tried to use scale_colour_manual to create a color set but, the environment created has only 16 colors. How can I increase the number of colors present in the environment created?

the code I am using can be replicated as follow:

```
colour_genus <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(90, 5) #to be random names

nb.cols = nrow(colour_genus) #to set the length of my string
MyPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12,"Set1"))(nb.cols) # the palette of choice
colGenus <- scale_color_manual(name = colour_genus, values = MyPalette)
```

The output formed contains only 16 values, so when I try to apply it to a figure with 90 factors, it complains I have only 16 values

```
abundance <- runif(90, min = 10, max = 100)
my_data <- data.frame(colour_genus, abundance)

p <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = colour_genus, y= abundance)) +
  geom_bar(aes(color = colour_genus, fill = colour_genus), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance\n") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
p + theme(legend.text= element_text(size=7, face="bold"), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2)) + scale_fill_manual(values=colGenus)
```

The following error shows:
Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 90 needed but only 16 provided.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You could make a vector of 90 colours in many different ways. But I am not sure that a plot with 90 colours is very useful: they are going to be difficult to distinguish and the legend will be huge

Comment: Hello, a vector-only would not work, since as mentioned, some species are present in one plot but not another. So I need to have the color assigned to a specific name. So, plot one has random 30 samples, but 2 has 10 of the first 30 and 20 different ones. And I want that the repeated species always show in the same color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you know all your 90 bacci names in front of plotting, you can try.

```
set.seed(123)
colour_genus <- sort(stringi::stri_rand_strings(90, 5))#to be random names. I sorted the vector to illustrate the output better (optional). 
MyPalette <- sample(colors(), length(colour_genus))
# named vector for scale_fill
names(MyPalette) <- colour_genus

# data
abundance <- runif(90, min = 10, max = 100)
my_data <- data.frame(colour_genus, abundance)

# two sets to show results
set1 <- my_data[20:30,]
set2 <- my_data[25:35,]
ggplot(set1, aes(x = colour_genus, y= abundance)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = colour_genus)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = MyPalette)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(set2, aes(x = colour_genus, y= abundance)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = colour_genus)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = MyPalette)
```

[image]